# Excel - how to copy all colums in a row based on a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm new to macros and hope somebody can help
Trying to make a report from a datasheet that meets some conditions.
I need to fetch all the data (cells) in a row e.g. that meet the condition <1 in column 10 and copy those cells/row to a new sheet. I cant find any functions i Excel so I hope a not to advanced macro which I can modify can do the trick.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- Open a copy of your excel sheet containing all the data
- press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
- open sheet1 from the left pane and insert the code below

  ```
  Sub mymacro()
    For myrow = 1 To Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
      If Cells(myrow, 8) < 1 Then
        i = i + 1
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(myrow).Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows(i)
      End If
    Next myrow
  End Sub
  ```
- go back to your sheet and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and execute your macro

This code will run until the last used row, check if the value of 8th column is < 1 and if yes, copy the whole row to the next free row in sheet 2.

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try. Its a lot of rows with cars we have sold. In column "H" I add a "1" if the car is delivered. In every end of month I have to send a orderreserve and I then want to just fetch all the rows with cars that is not delivered and make a report to send. It's maybe a cumbersome way to do it, but i'm a novice :-)

Comment: marvellous :-)
If I can bother you more I'm looking for the data who occurs in row 14 to 1000. maybe it will be quicker when the array is defined. Ok, I promise that I will try harder to learn macro programming my self :-)

Comment: But I want you to learn something :)  What you want is really very simple. I give you a hint and you try it, ok? You have to edit line 2.